# Shell Script that parses multiple files and adds in a line if a condition is met?

Tags: shell, unix, sed, scripting

I'm trying to write a shell script that reads over a hundred files containing multiple sections of parameters in each file, just to modify one line. If a section in one file does not contain "ELLIPSOID_CODE = 123", add in line "ELLIPSOID_CODE = DEFAULT" before "OUTPUT_PARAMETER". If a section in one file does contain "ELLIPSOID CODE = 123", don't do anything. I am having trouble parsing in shell script to get this to work. I have an example of a file and my attempted code below.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
NUM_RUNS = 2 

INPUT_FILE = /home/autotest
OUTPUT_PROJECTION_TYPE = BLAH
ELLIPSOID_CODE = 123
OUTPUT_PARAMETER = BLAH
OUT_FILE = /home/autotest

INPUT_FILE = /home/autotest
OUTPUT_PROJECTION_TYPE = BLAH
OUTPUT_PARAMETER = BLAH
OUT_FILE = /home/autotest

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#Adds in the line "ELLIPSOID_CODE = DEFAULT" before OUTPUT_PARAMETER 

dir="/home/autotest/test/"
for i in "$dir"/*;
do
    sed -i 's:OUTPUT_PARAMETER:ELLIPSOID_CODE = DEFAULT\nOUTPUT_PARAMETER:' "$i";
done
```

My code adds in the ELLIPSOID_CODE = DEFAULT in every section no matter, when I just want it to add that line in in the second section of just this one file. Just to clarify I'm trying to get it to look like this:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
NUM_RUNS = 2 

INPUT_FILE = /home/autotest
OUTPUT_PROJECTION_TYPE = BLAH
ELLIPSOID_CODE = 123
OUTPUT_PARAMETER = BLAH
OUT_FILE = /home/autotest

INPUT_FILE = /home/autotest
OUTPUT_PROJECTION_TYPE = BLAH
ELLIPSOID_CODE = DEFAULT
OUTPUT_PARAMETER = BLAH
OUT_FILE = /home/autotest

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use awk?

Comment: Yes, I could use awk.

Comment: Then use awk. Find INPUT_FILE, if you find OUTPUT_PARAMETER before you find ELLIPSOID_CODE  then add the line you want. Loop.

Comment: Ok thank you @EmeryLapinski, that makes sense. Do you think you could write that line with awk just because I am unfamiliar with it? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Answer generously provided by @RomanPerekhrest from Unix & Linux, but just wanted it to be covered here as well.

**`sed`** solution:

```
sed -i '/^OUTPUT_PROJECTION_TYPE = .*/{ 
       N; s/OUTPUT_PARAMETER = .*/ELLIPSOID_CODE = DEFAULT\n&/; 
   }' /home/autotest/test/*
```

- `/^OUTPUT_PROJECTION_TYPE = .*/` - for each line started with pattern `OUTPUT_PROJECTION_TYPE = .*`(where `^` is regex anchor indicating the start of the string/line):
- `N` - add a newline to the pattern space, then append the next line of input to the pattern space
- `s/OUTPUT_PARAMETER = .*/ELLIPSOID_CODE = DEFAULT\n&/` - if the next line is `OUTPUT_PARAMETER = .*` (which means that `ELLIPSOID_CODE = ...` is missed) - prepend it with default line `ELLIPSOID_CODE = DEFAULT`. (`&` points to the whole matched string)

Comment: You could link the answer from U&L.